# MassTransit connecting to RabbitMQ vhost starting with slash

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, .net-core-3.1

I am currently trying to implement RabbitMQ in .NET Core 3.1 using MassTransit. I am running into an issue getting started, the RabbitMQ server is running 3.8.5 and Erlang 22.0.7.

The issue occurs during the connection to the RabbitMQ Server. The vhost starts with a / and according the documentation
[RabbitMQ URI Specification Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf4ZA.png)

That should be percent encoded into the URI as %2f

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<RequestConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(provider =>
                {
                    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                    {
                        var uri = new Uri("amqps://rmq.domain.net:5671/%2ftestvhost");
                        cfg.Host(uri, host =>
                        {
                            host.Username("testuser");
                            host.Password("testpassword");
                        });

                    });

                    return bus;
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
}
```

After attempting to run the connection is closed and the following error is outputted

```
 ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=530, text='NOT_ALLOWED - vhost %2ftestvhost not found', classId=10, methodId=40
```

The output from the rabbitmq server is

```
[error] <0.11481.4> Error on AMQP connection <0.11481.4> (IP -> IP - iisexpress, user: 'testuser', state: opening):
vhost %2ftestvhost not found
[info] <0.11481.4> closing AMQP connection <0.11481.4> (IP -> IP - iisexpress, vhost: 'none', user: 'testuser')
```

The final message about vhost being 'none' is a little interesting I suspect that 'none' is a default for unknown vhosts.

My question is am I missing something, the URI doesn't seem to map properly to the vhost?
Is their an explicit setting I am missing for a vhost starting with a slash?

I've tried

- Adding a second slash in the front
- Changing the configuration to use cfg.Host(hostname, port, vhost)

Comment: Why on earth would you start a vhost name with a slash anyway?

Comment: When you changed it to use `(host,port,vhost)` did you use the actual slash, instead of the `%2F`?

Comment: System admin decision to start it with a /. Using the other way to construct a host, I ended up getting a 
`RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable`

Comment: Educate your sysadmin, seriously. Zero sense.